# EndpointNotFound: public endpoint for hpext:dns service in RegionOne region not found

Tags: python-2.7, openstack-neutron

I have installed designate client on the same box where designate server is running with OpenStack Juno. After setting environment by issuing . .venv/bin/activate and keystone variables by issuing this command keystonerc_admin.

When I try to run designate --debug server-list command I am getting this error:

EndpointNotFound: public endpoint for hpext:dns service in RegionOne region not found

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. This was my mistake. I have exported hpext:dns in keystone_admin and .bashrc file.

This value is very much specific if anyone is using hp cloud and they are logging into their geos.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that value is from before designate was an incubated project, but was running in HP Cloud.

The standard 'dns' service should be used for anyone not using the HP Public Cloud service (it is the default in python-designateclient, so you shouldn't have to do anything)